# Working with production record types in a managed package

Tags: managed-package, record-type

I have to create some triggers and flows in a 2nd-generation managed package that reference a record type developer name. That's fine, except that the record types that I need to reference are unmanaged in my production org.

These flows and triggers can work just fine in my scratch org, but then when creating a new package version, I either get the following in flow:

```
"field integrity exception: unknown (A condition has a reference to "$Record.RecordType.DeveloperName", which doesn't exist."
```

Or I get an error with one of my triggers stating that the field RecordType doesn't exist.

Any ideas on a workaround or what I could be missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to check to see if record types are enabled on the object you're dealing with - one of the pains of being an ISV is that you have no control over the environment where your code runs. I'm not 100% sure on how you do that from flow. In Apex you can use the describe methods to see if the `RecordTypeId` field exists or not.

If record types are enabled, and you want to avoid a hard reference the best bet is to query for it by name, in flow and in Apex.

In Apex you'd do something like this - notice there are no hard references involved:

```
Account a = new Account();
String recordType = 'PersonAccount';

if (Schema.SObjectType.Account.fields.GetMap().Get('RecordTypeId') != null) {
    a.RecordTypeId = Database.query('select Id from RecordType where SobjectType = \'Account\' and DeveloperName = :someRTName');
}
```

For your use case, where you want to know if a lead's record type is within a certain list of record type developer names you could do something like this:

```
Boolean recordTypesEnabled = Schema.SObjectType.Account.fields.GetMap().Get('RecordTypeId') != null;

Set<Id> rtIds = new Set<Id>();
List<String> rtnames = new List<String>{'name1','name2','name3'};

for(SObject s : Database.Query('SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectName = \'Lead\' AND DeveloperName in : rtnames')) {
  rtIds.add(s.Id);
}

for(Lead l : trigger.new) {

  if(recordTypesEnabled && l.get('RecordTypeId') != null && rtIds.contains(l.get('RecordTypeId'))) {
      // do something
  }
}
```

I've not compiled this code but it should give you an idea of what to do!

Comment: Thanks I'm on the right track with this. How would I do this in a trigger on Lead, for example to check in the loop of leads if the lead record type belongs to 1 of multiple developer names?

Comment: @user1702965 See my edit above!

Comment: This worked. Only modification is that I needed to cast to ID:

 Id leadRecordTypeId = (Id)lead.get('RecordTypeId'); // Cast to Id
           // Check if RecordType is enabled, the Lead has a RecordTypeId, and it's one of the target types
            if (recordTypesEnabled && leadRecordTypeId != null && rtIds.contains(leadRecordTypeId)) {